# how can I make echo print to a file in a certain way

Tags: bash

(Let's pretend that "|" is the text cursor)
When I print text to a file using echo (`echo "Hello" > file.txt`), this text appears in the file: `|Hello`. I know it sounds silly, but how can I move `|` to the front of "Hello" without doing it manually?

Comment: Text files don't contain cursors, that's part of the user interface of your text editor, and will depend on whether your editor supports commands to move the cursor around.

Comment: Are you saying that when you open a file in your editor, the editing cursor starts at the beginning of the line? And you want to automatically move it to the end of the line? That's really up to the editor, and not related to `bash` or `echo`.

Comment: The editor Vim does support commands to move the cursor, passed in when opening a file, so you could run `vim -c 'startinsert!' file.txt` which will put the cursor after `Hello` and leave Vim in insert mode.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Thanks! It worked.

Comment: Please read the [help] before posting more Qs here. This is off-topic and would be better posted to https://superuser.com or https://vi.stackexchange.com . Good luck.